# Python - multiple inheritance with same name

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

I have main class as:

```
class OptionsMenu(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        try:
            self.menu = getattr(self, name)()
        except:
            self.menu = None

    @staticmethod
    def cap():
        return ['a', 'b']
```

and have a child class override as:

```
class OptionsMenu(OptionsMenu):
    @staticmethod
    def cap():
        return ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

The first class gives the menu options for default template, while next gives for some other template.

I want another class `OptionsMenu` derived from child class, and get the list (`['a', 'b', 'c']`) and make changes to that.

Is this achievable in python? If yes, how may I achieve this?

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Why do you want to have the same name?

Comment: It is possible if the two `OptionsMenu` are in distinct modules, but... why that?

Comment: You derived a second class, what's preventing you from deriving a third one?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing stops you from getting result of parent's static function:

```
class OptionsMenu:
    @staticmethod
    def cap():
        return ['a', 'b', 'c']


class OptionsMenu(OptionsMenu):
    @staticmethod
    def cap():
        lst = super(OptionsMenu, OptionsMenu).cap()  # ['a', 'b', 'c']
        lst.append('d')
        return lst

print(OptionsMenu.cap())  # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

But as noted to give same class names for different classes **is very bad idea**! It will lead to many problems in future.

Try to think, why do you want same names for different classes.
May be they should have different names?

```
class OptionsMenu

class SpecialOptionsMenu(OptionsMenu)
```

Or may be as soon as `cap()` is static method, make different functions out of `OptionsMenu`?

```
def cap1(): return ['a', 'b', 'c']

def cap2(): return cap1() + ['d']
```